# How do i adjust the position of a Bootstrap's Tooltip for a certain element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have these buttons/anchors right here and a Bootstrap made tooltip :

```
<a id="btn1" class="mybutton" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="my tooltip">
    Hover Me To Display Tooltip
</a>

<a id="btn2" class="mybutton" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="my tooltip">
    Hover Me To Display Tooltip
</a>
```

and combine it with the jQuery code which is this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mybutton").tooltip();
});
```

it will work perfectly fine, displaying the tooltip on the right.

but how can i change the position of the tooltip of only button1 using CSS, so that i can move it further to the right? without moving the button2's tooltip?

Answer (score 7):

Apply `data-placement="right"` data attribute to the element where you want to change position of toolip;

You can also set. `top` ,`left`,`right`,`bottom`,`auto`.

If you want more about tooltip. Check [bootstrap tooltip settings](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Comment: i know this but, what i want to do is move it further

Comment: Yes you can override css for tooltio right, this will affect all tooltips on the right , do it like this ->                                         `.tooltip.right {
  -moz-transform: translateX(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50px);
  -o-transform: translateX(50px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  transform: translateX(50px);
}`                                                                                               @Twish

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap4, as it's using "transform: translate3d" to position the tip, left & top should be used in CSS to adjust the tip's position. For example, to move the tip down 10px and right 10px:

```css
.tooltip-class {
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Look at the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) for `tooltip`. You can do something like this to change the tooltip's position:

`$( "#btn1" ).tooltip({ position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" } });`

The `#btn1` selector selects by id and will only match the first button.

You can find details on what the position object means [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/).

Edit:

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PaQU3/1). You can change the values and see how it works.

Comment: i dont get this part { position: { my: "left+15 center", at :"right center" }

Comment: @Twish added another link.

Comment: i tried changing the left+15 to bottom+15 but it did not change the position, :(

Comment: alright it's already wokring, but i'm using bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js as external sources? and it doesn't seem to be working :O

Comment: Just for clarification: The question asks for positioning "Bootstrap tooltip". The answer uses "JqueryUI tooltip". Both are completely different implementations.